# Unable to add Java language server for code linting

Tags: java, language-server-protocol

I wanted to add language server for code linting in java. I was following this eclipse ls
https://github.com/eclipse-jdtls/eclipse.jdt.ls

```
 java \            
    -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 \
    -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 \
    -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product \
    -Dlog.level=ALL \
    -Xmx1G \
    --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM \
    --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
    -jar ./plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.700.v20231214-2017.jar \
    -configuration ./config_mac \
    -data /Users/yadavdipesh/Documents
```

but it's not working.
[image: I am seeing this, now I don't know what to further]

what to do after getting this, the terminal is running it is not stopped now what should I do?

```
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector
Jan 18, 2024 6:09:12 AM org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
INFO: Registered provider ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer of service jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer in bundle ch.qos.logback.classic
Jan 18, 2024 6:09:12 AM org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
INFO: Registered provider ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider of service org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider in bundle ch.qos.logback.classic
Content-Length: 127

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":3,"message":"18-Jan-2024, 6:09:13 am Main thread is waiting"}}
```